# iptables doesn't recognise REDIRECT as target

Tags: pi-3, kernel, modules, iptables, port-forwarding

Trying to redirect traffic using iptables v1.6 and the following line:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 67 -j REDIRECT --to-port 6767
```

which results in the following output:

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

building the rule option by option breaks when adding the -j REDIRECT option.

running:

```
/usr/src $ find /lib/modules/*/ -type f -iname '*.ko' | grep redirect
```

shows

> /lib/modules/4.14.79+/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/ebt_redirect.ko
>
> /lib/modules/4.14.79+/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_nat_redirect.ko
>
> /lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/ebt_redirect.ko
>
> /lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_nat_redirect.ko

running v9 stretch, kernel 4.9.80-v7+ on a pi3.

I'm assuming i need to recompile iptables but not sure.

Comment: `kernel 4.9.80-v7+`Looks to me that your kernel and modules are out of sync. Are you sure that you're still using a 4.9 kernel? What does e.g. `uname -a` say?